# How do I set multiple --conf table parameters in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Multiple Answers on stackoverflow for AWS Glue say to set the --conf table parameter. However, sometimes in a job we'll need to set multiple --conf key value pairs in 1 job.

I've tried the following ways to have multiple --conf values set all resulting in error:

- add another table parameter called --conf. This results in the AWS Dashboard removing the 2nd parameter named --conf and sets focus to the value of the 1st parameter named --conf. Terraform also just considers both table parameters with key `--conf` to be equal and overwrites the value in the 1st parameter with the 2nd's value.
- separate the config key value parameters with a space in the value of the table --conf parameter. E.G. `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=7g spark.yarn.executor.memory=7g`. This results in a failure to start the job.
- separate the config key value parameters with a comma in the value of the table --conf parameter. E.G. `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024, spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=7g, spark.yarn.executor.memory=7g`. This results in a failure to start the job.
- set the value of the --conf to have `--conf` string separate each key value. E.G. `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=7g --conf spark.yarn.executor.memory=7g`. This results in the glue job hanging.

How do I set multiple --conf table parameters in AWS Glue?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can pass multiple parameters as below:

**Key:** --conf

**value:** spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=7g --conf spark.yarn.executor.memory=7g

This has worked for me.

Comment: This resulted in the glue job hanging. I will try again to confirm.