# AWS Glue: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog': org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I have a Glue job in Python, which write individual parquet files to Delta Lake in S3.

```py
import sys

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

raw_parquet_path = "s3://my-bucket/data/raw-parquet/motor/"
delta_table_path = (
    "s3://my-bucket/data/delta-tables/my_table/"
)
partition_list = ["_event_id"]

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [raw_parquet_path],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

# Script generated for node sink_to_delta_lake
additional_options = {
    "path": delta_table_path,
    "write.parquet.compression-codec": "snappy",
    "mergeSchema": "true",
}
sink_to_delta_lake_node3_df = S3bucket_node1.toDF()
sink_to_delta_lake_node3_df.write.format("delta").options(
    **additional_options
).partitionBy(*partition_list).mode("append").save()

job.commit()
```

I got error

```
An error occurred while calling o111.save. Failed to find data source: delta. Please find packages at
```

I added Job details -> Advanced properties -> Job parameters

- `--conf`: `spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog`
- `--packages`: `io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0`

(Note `--conf` is in one line based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59261013/2000548))

[image]

However, then the error becomes

> An error occurred while calling o100.getDynamicFrame. Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog': org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am missing io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0 JAR file, I will have to upload JAR file in S3 and then set the S3 path in I added Job details -> Advanced properties -> Libraries -> Dependent JARs path.

However, I found a simple way instead of providing the JAR file manually.

All I need is at Job details -> Advanced properties -> Job parameters, adding

`--datalake-format`: `delta`

[image]

Now the Glue job can succeed running!

Here is a copy of the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html) of `--datalake-formats`:

> Supported in AWS Glue 3.0 and later versions.
>
> Specifies the data lake framework to use. AWS Glue adds the required
> JAR files for the frameworks that you specify into the `classpath`.
> For more information, see Using data lake frameworks with AWS Glue ETL
> jobs.
>
> You can specify one or more of the following values, separated by a
> comma:
>
> - `hudi`
> - `delta`
> - `iceberg`